# Why awk 'NR%2 == 1?ORS=";":ORS="\n"' give syntax error?

Tags: awk

I am solving a Hackerrank question where the output is

```
A 25 27 50;B 35 37 75
C 75 78 80;D 99 88 76
```

for input

```
A 25 27 50
B 35 37 75
C 75 78 80
D 99 88 76.
```

I am using `ORS` to do the above task. But I don't know why runtime error is coming?

```
awk 'NR%2 == 1?ORS=";":ORS="\n"'
```

Error coming is

```
awkNR: cmd. line:1: Possible syntax error
```

Comment: There is no error in the code that you show. Please double check that you have copied the exact `awk` code that you say you're using. Tested with GNU `awk`, `mawk` and OpenBSD `awk`, all produce the correct output.

Comment: Also make sure that you know how the `awk` code was being executed.  If your `awk` command was stored in a file used with `awk -f`, then there _would_ have been an issue with it if it was written exactly as you have shown (it's a shell command, not an `awk` command).

Comment: I am running exactly the same code on hackerrank editor. The problem is provided on this link https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/awk-4/problem SIr, can you run the above command and see the error comming.

Comment: I am getting confused is there problem in the editor or with the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Busybox `awk` seems to need parentheses around the last two operands.

I get the same error with

```
$ busybox awk 'NR%2 == 1?ORS=";":ORS="\n"' file
awkNR: cmd. line:1: Possible syntax error
```

but it works with

```
$ busybox awk 'NR%2 == 1?(ORS=";"):(ORS="\n")' file
A 25 27 50;B 35 37 75
C 75 78 80;D 99 88 76
```

Comment: Adding parentheses is solving the issue. But I am still confused why the error came with the original code? Should I conclude Hackerrank editor uses Busybox awk version in the backend?

Comment: I don't know Hackerrank, so can't really tell, but it looks like it.

Comment: Hackerrank is coding practice platform based in India. The link to the question is https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/awk-4/problem . Since parentheses is solving the error maybe they are using busybox version only. Thank You for the help.

Answer (score 14):

Unparenthesized ternary expressions cause syntax errors in various awk versions in various contexts, not just the context and awk version already mentioned. Heres another example on MacOS:

```
$ awk --version
awk version 20070501

$ awk 'BEGIN{print 1 == 2 ? 3 : 4}'
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    {print 1 >>>  == <<<
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1

$ awk 'BEGIN{print (1 == 2 ? 3 : 4)}'
4

$ awk 'BEGIN{print (1 == 2) ? 3 : 4}'
4
```

Of the 2 that work, I find `print (1 == 2 ? 3 : 4)` the more readable, especially when you get nested ternaries:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print (1 == 2 ? (6 == 7 ? 8 : 3) : 4)}'
4

$ awk 'BEGIN{print (1 == 2) ? (6 == 7) ? 8 : 3 : 4}'
4
```

so that's what I always use and the additionally add parens around just the conditions if/when useful, usually for readability.

Since parenthesized ternaries are always easier to read than unparenthesized, there's simply no good reason to ever write one without parentheses.

You should also never use an assignment in a conditional context unless you **need** the result of the assignment to be evaluated as a condition, which you don't.

What you're trying to do should be written as:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NR%2 ? ";" : RS)} 1' file
A 25 27 50;B 35 37 75
C 75 78 80;D 99 88 76
```

Comment: At least Busybox does parse `{ORS = NR%2 ? ";" : RS}` correctly, though. What's easier to read is personal, of course :)

Answer (score 0):

Rewritten to avoid the awkward quoted strings, your construct is like this:

```
1 > 0 ? a = 1 : a = 2
```

It's not exactly ambiguous, since it can only be usefully parsed like `(1 > 0) ? (a = 1) : (a = 2)`. But according to POSIX, [the assignment has lower priority than the conditional operator](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/awk.html) `?:`, so Busybox may be trying to parse it like `(1 > 0 ? a) = (1 : a) = (2)`, which doesn't really work.

It also doesn't work in C (Debian's gcc 6.3.0-18+deb9u1), so I wouldn't say Busybox is entirely wrong here:

```
/tmp$ cat ternary.c
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    1 > 0 ? a = 11 : a = 22;
}
/tmp$ gcc -Wall -o ternary ternary.c 
ternary.c: In function ‘main’:
ternary.c:4:24: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     1 > 0 ? a = 11 : a = 22;
                        ^
```

(I suppose the language lawyers at stackoverflow could tell exactly why and how that should or should not work.)

You could add the parenthesis around the assignments, but that **should** be written as `a = 1 > 0 ? 11 : 22`. This is the reason assignment does have lower precedence than `?:`, if it didn't, that would parse as `(a = (1 > 0)) ? 11 : 22` which usually isn't what you want.

On the other hand, if you were to want the target of the assignment to change based on the condition, you **really should** use a full `if` sentence for clarity instead of `1 > 0 ? (a = 11) : (b = 22)`.

Comment: Without parenthesis is correctly working in GNU Awk, OPENBSD awk. I think precedence is not the issue.

Comment: @ShubhamKumar, my point was that it might not be correct. But looking more closely at the grammar, I may be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

perhaps :

```
echo "${cccccccc}"
echo
echo "${cccccccc}" \
\
| mawk -F. 'ORS=substr(";\n",_-(NR%_--),NF=_++)' \_=2 OFS= | ecp

A 25 27 50
B 35 37 75
C 75 78 80
D 99 88 76.

 
A 25 27 50;B 35 37 75
C 75 78 80;D 99 88 76
```

or even simpler - a solution that uses leverages lots of built-in variables to do the heavy lifting :

```
mawk -F. 'NF=sub(FS,(NR % _)?":" :"\n",ORS)' OFS='' \_=2
```

If you prefer a `getline` approach, then you don't even have to spend effort on calculating  `NR % 2` :

```
 echo;  echo "${cccccccc}"
 echo;  echo "${cccccccc}" \
 \
 | mawk -F. '$!_=$-_=sprintf("%s;%s",$( NF ^= !NF ),
                                     $!(NF  = getline))' OFS=''

A 25 27 50
B 35 37 75
C 75 78 80
D 99 88 76.

 
A 25 27 50;B 35 37 75
C 75 78 80;D 99 88 76
```

If you're into really exotic syntax, perhaps even

```
mawk -F. 'sub("^",($!(NF = !_))";",$!(NF = getline))' OFS=


A 25 27 50
B 35 37 75
C 75 78 80
D 99 88 76.

 
A 25 27 50;B 35 37 75
C 75 78 80;D 99 88 76
```