# GNU awk --traditional vs --posix

Tags: awk, macos, compatibility

So, GNU awk has some extensions that are missing in the macOS awk.

I want to be sure that my awk program also runs on the macOS awk (which I don't have access to).

Now GNU awk has two different compatibility flags and I'm not sure which to use: `--traditional` and `--posix`.

The latter is more strict. Does `--traditional` suffice to achieve compatibility with the macOS awk?

Comment: When in doubt, go with POSIX. It will work well on BSD styled kernels such as  XNU (MacOS).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No because

1. MacOS implements features that are part of POSIX but weren't part of BWK awk (which `gawk --traditional` is intended to be compatible with) such as RE intervals so some language constructs don't mean the same across the 2 variants despite being valid in both.
2. MacOS awk has bugs that aren't present in GNU awk so a working gawk script could fail on MacOS no matter what options you give it.
3. Both awks can/do implement functionality that's undefined by POSIX or the "traditional" awk spec however they like.

So `--posix` will be closer to what you want than `--traditional` but still has differences with MacOS, and neither option nor any other option does what you want - guarantee a gawk script will run the same in MacOS awk.

1. For example, with gawk (which does not support RE intervals like `{2}` in traditional mode but does in posix mode):

   ```
   $ awk --version | head -1
   GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0

   $ echo 'ab{2}c' | awk --traditional '/b{2}/'
   ab{2}c

   $ echo 'ab{2}c' | awk --posix '/b{2}/'
   $

   $ echo 'ab{2}c' | awk --traditional '/b\{2\}/'
   awk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\{' is not a known regexp operator
   awk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\}' is not a known regexp operator
   ab{2}c
   ```

   whereas with MacOS which does support RE intervals:

   ```
   $ awk --version | head -1
   awk version 20200816

   $ echo 'ab{2}c' | awk '/b{2}/'
   $

   $ echo 'ab{2}c' | awk '/b\{2\}/'
   ab{2}c
   ```
2. For example, with gawk:

   ```
   $ awk 'BEGIN{print 1 == 2 ? 3 : 4}'
   4

   $ awk --traditional 'BEGIN{print 1 == 2 ? 3 : 4}'
   4

   $ awk --posix 'BEGIN{print 1 == 2 ? 3 : 4}'
   4
   ```

   whereas with MacOS:

   ```
   $ awk 'BEGIN{print 1 == 2 ? 3 : 4}'
   awk: syntax error at source line 1
    context is
    BEGIN{print 1 >>>  == <<<
   awk: illegal statement at source line 1
   awk: illegal statement at source line 1
   ```

   See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/588743/133219 for more info on that specific error.
3. Another difference in how handling a directory as a file name is handled:

   ```
   $ mkdir foo
   $ echo 7 > bar
   ```

   with GNU awk:

   ```
   $ awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' foo bar
   awk: warning: command line argument `foo' is a directory: skipped
   bar 7

   $ awk --traditional '{print FILENAME, $0}' foo bar
   awk: fatal: cannot open file `foo' for reading (Is a directory)

   $ awk --posix '{print FILENAME, $0}' foo bar
   awk: fatal: cannot open file `foo' for reading (Is a directory)
   ```

   and MacOS awk:

   ```
   $ awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' foo bar
   bar 7
   ```

Comment: `--posix` would be closer for busybox awk also?

Comment: @thanasisp I've never used busybox awk myself but I just found a comment about busybox in the gawk manual (https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Other-Versions.html) that says `It includes a full implementation of POSIX awk` so in that case, yes `--posix` would be the right flag.