# Bash script to calculate within a CSV with or without zero

Tags: bash, awk, calculator

I have a script here that I am working with.
I would now like to expand this.

```
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 awk -F ';' -v OFS=';' '
  {print $0, NR == 1 ? "Price" : $1 ? $1 : $3 * 1.2}' < file.csv
```

If there is no zero in column 1, calculate field 3 with 1.2
But I would like to have, if field 1 is zero or nothing, calculate field 3 with 1.2
is that possible?

This is my spreadsheet or CSV file:

```
Sales Price;External ID;Cost;Internal reference;Name;Sales Description
73;1000-04;141,35;1000-04;Jabra GN 1000 RHL Remote Handset Lifter;Manueller Lifter bzw. Hook-Switch
0;0440-729;61,72;0440-729;Jabra GN 1000 RHL, zbh. für Siemens Optiset; Siemens Optiset Telefone
215;2126-82-04;221,8;2126-82-04;Jabra 2100 Mono QD 3-in-1 Set;Typ: 82 E-STD, Noise-Cancelling Mikrofonarm: Flexibel
0;01.01.8800;11,3;01.01.8800;Jabra Kabel QD -> RJ10 Standard spiral;RJ10
```

This is what the result should look like

```
Sales Price;External ID;Cost;Internal reference;Name;Sales Description;Price
73;1000-04;141,35;1000-04;Jabra GN 1000 RHL Remote Handset Lifter;Manueller Lifter bzw. Hook-Switch;73
0;0440-729;61,72;0440-729;Jabra GN 1000 RHL, zbh. für Siemens Optiset; Siemens Optiset Telefone;74,064
215;2126-82-04;221,8;2126-82-04;Jabra 2100 Mono QD 3-in-1 Set;Typ: 82 E-STD, Noise-Cancelling Mikrofonarm: Flexibel;215
0;01.01.8800;11,3;01.01.8800;Jabra Kabel QD -> RJ10 Standard spiral;RJ10;13,56
```

I have now created calc.sh with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
    {
        if (NR == 1) val = "Price"
        else         val = ($9 ? $5 * 1.2 : $9)
        print $0, val
    }
' /test.csv
```

and I run the file like this:

calc.sh > /opt/price/result.csv

this is the result:

```
Sales Price;External ID;Cost;Internal reference;Name;Sales Description
;Price
73;1000-04;141,35;1000-04;Jabra GN 1000 RHL Remote Handset Lifter;Manueller Lifter bzw. Hook-Switch
;
0;0440-729;61,72;0440-729;Jabra GN 1000 RHL, zbh. für Siemens Optiset; Siemens Optiset Telefone
;
215;2126-82-04;221,8;2126-82-04;Jabra 2100 Mono QD 3-in-1 Set;Typ: 82 E-STD, Noise-Cancelling Mikrofonarm: Flexibel
;
0;01.01.8800;11,3;01.01.8800;Jabra Kabel QD -> RJ10 Standard spiral;RJ10;
```

1. Price is on the 2nd line. Why?
2. Can I also specify somewhere that Price should be output in column xx?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to add a sample input and the output you want? It'd make it easier to see what's expected. Anyway, `$1` as a condition should be falsy if the field is zero or empty, so it looks like what you have would already pretty mcuh do what you're saying. A string would be truthy, though, but you can force it into a number by using `$1 + 0`. FWIW, I'd avoid nested `?:` conditionals, as they can be a bit difficult to parse mentally.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is your data using comma (`,`) as the decimal point?

Comment: The edits so far have not helped. What kind of calculation are you tring to perform? Rows 2 and 3 if your example seem to cover both the pre-conditions you specified, but in both cases the values for the 3rd column are unchanged in the output (141,35 & 61,72).

Comment: @symcbean In the first row are headings of the columns.
If there is no value or zero in column one, I want to take the value from column 3 and multiply the value by 1.2 and write it in a new column X

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes I use comma as decimal point. Why?

Comment: Regarding "Morton's answer is a bit unclear to me. Where do I embed the file then?" - I updated [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/742026/133219) to show exactly how to write/use the script.

Answer (score 3):

To change your logic from what you have:

> If there is no zero in column 1, calculate field 3 with 1.2

to what you would like to have:

> if field 1 is zero or nothing, calculate field 3 with 1.2

just change what you have:

```
$1 ? $1 : $3 * 1.2
```

to either negate the condition:

```
!$1 ? $1 : $3 * 1.2
```

or swap the order of the values:

```
$1 ? $3 * 1.2 : $1
```

swapping the order of the values is better since it avoids a negative in the condition, `$1 ?`, part and a double negative in the "else", `: $1`, part.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_conditional_operator for how to read/use ternary expressions.

Having said that - don't nest ternary expressions as that makes your code hard to read, and always put parens around your ternary expressions to make them easier to read and to avoid syntax errors in some contexts in some awks (e.g. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/588743/133219).

So instead of:

```
{print $0, NR == 1 ? "Price" : $1 ? $3 * 1.2 : $1}
```

you should write:

```
{
    if (NR == 1) val = "Price"
    else         val = ($1 ? $3 * 1.2 : $1)
    print $0, val
}
```

or similar.

Also, instead of:

```
awk -F ';' -v OFS=';' 'script'
```

consider using:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} script'
```

so you don't hard-code the same separator (`;`) in 2 places when you need both FS and OFS to have the same value - it makes your code slightly clearer and means you only need to change 1 place if/when you decide to change the separator.

I see you're having trouble understanding the above so to be clear here's what I'm suggesting your complete script should be:

```
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
    {
        if (NR == 1) val = "Price"
        else         val = ($1 ? $3 * 1.2 : $1)
        print $0, val
    }
' file.csv
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Locale-influences-conversions for why you need `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` in a locale where the decimal separator is `,` instead of `.`.

Comment: Can awk use comma as the decimal point "just like that"? (see their data)

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, awk will use whatever the decimal point is defined to be for the user's locale. There's a caveat for gawk but that's what `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` is handling.

Comment: Can I output the output only in a specific column? e.g. column 50?
I don't want the output to be in the last column.

Comment: @dima1002 yes but [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged on this forum. [Accept an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to this question you asked and then ask a new question about that if you need help.